# JavaScript event timestamps not consistent

Tags: javascript, firefox

I notice that when I click one element on my site e.timeStamp is reported by Firebug in  the event handler as a 9-digit number, like 866523917, and when I click a different element e.timeStamp is reported in that handler by Firebug as a 16-digit number, like
1376344365954000. Why the difference?

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by: *when i click*? who fires the event? please provide a live demo illustrating this or otherwise elaborate on the issue.

Comment: Sounds interesting. `event.timeStamp` is the number of milliseconds (since the epoch) at which the event was created. There shouldn't be such a big difference. Can you present a sample code?

Comment: Here's a demo - http://jsfiddle.net/stevea/zTm9L/1/.  The 1376344365954000 is the right number, since that breaks down to 43 years. But for some reason, the one above is coming in around 877246085.  These are ms, since it changes about 1000 per second, so the number is about 240 hours.

Comment: What do you mean by "the one above"? There is only one button I can se e in the fiddle.

Comment: See https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=238041.

Comment: By "the one above" I meant the one in the jsfiddle.  I wasn't able to create a jsfiddle where the timestamp reported was the 16-digit number so the jsfiddle above only shows the 9-digit timestamp..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [defined in standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Events-20001113/events.html#Events-Event-timeStamp) `timeStamp` returns number of milliseconds since epoch:

> Used to specify the time (in milliseconds relative to the epoch) at
>   which the event was created. Due to the fact that some systems may not
>   provide this information the value of timeStamp may be not available
>   for all events. When not available, a value of 0 will be returned.

However, there is no strict definition for epoch:

> Examples of epoch time are the time of the system start or 0:0:0 UTC
>   1st January 1970.

Some events are using first variant (system start) while others use time since 1970. Hence the difference. As a side note it's possible that `timeStamp` is not provided at all for some events, then its value will be `0`.

Comment: He's getting both types of values in Firefox. How does this answer explain it?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is Firefox.  I get the larger number (13 digits plus 3 zeroes) on Safari and Chrome, I came across some articles that say Firefox has a bug: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/10755.  One article suggested it might be reporting the time since the  last reboot.

I still don't understand why Firefox would report it one way for one interrupt and another way for another interrupt.  For my purposes I'll just use timestamp=Date.now() instead of e.timestamp.  That seems to be consistent at any interrupt.

Answer (score 0):

Instead `event.timestamp`, use `Date.now()`

Comment: I would add that, of course, the two are completely different things - the former is an attempt to provide the timestamp of the actual event as it fired, while the other simply returns the timestamp at the time of the `now` call. Of course, you are right in your silent assumption, that for many cases the difference won't matter, but still. We are again touching on Webs dark ages, when APIs were badly defined. It would not cost the powers that be to simply use one single epoch everywhere, otherwise we get to shuffle all the timestamps around, adding and subtracting them all the time.