# jQuery/javascript event.timestamp doesnt work

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, timestamp

I'm doing an exercise, but e.timestamp return initially return "-xxxx" value so the date.toDateString always return "Thu Jan 01 1970 click".
I've looked for an answer also on w3schools but also its solution doesn't work! I can't understand why TT_____TT
I use last version of Chrome!
This code works on Microsoft Edge. How I can make it universal?
Thank you guys :)

```
$(function() {

    $('li').on('click', function(e) {
        $('li span').remove();
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(e.timeStamp);
        var clicked = date.toDateString();
        $(this).append('<span class="date">' + clicked + ' ' + e.type + '</span>');
    });

});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18197401/javascript-event-timestamps-not-consistent

Comment: What is error you getting?

Comment: That date.toDateString always return "Thu Jan 01 1970 click"! Instead the click date!

Comment: Works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/y2a81agb/

Comment: My code works on Microsoft Edge. How I can make it universal?

Answer (score 8):

This is most likely due to recent (since version 49 ) [change to Event.timeStamp](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/01/high-res-timestamps?hl=en) in Chrome and Opera. These browsers are returning a `DOMHighResTimeStamp` instead of `DOMTimeStamp` which means the value is no longer an epoch time value and should not be converted or compared to a Date value.

BTW that code snippet has never worked in Firefox as it does not return an epoch timestamp for click events.

I suggest reading the article above. But in general, `Event.timeStamp` behavior is different across browsers and event types and it could also be subject to NTP time skews in some browsers. So it is rather tricky to use correctly.

If you want the epoch time instance of an event occurred it is safest to just use `Date.now()` inside handler. It loses some of the processing time but it is acceptable for many usecases:

```
$('li').on('click', function(e) {
   var clicked = (new Date()).toDateString();
   $(this).append('<span class="date">' + clicked + ' ' + e.type + '</span>');
});
```

However, most usecases actually need to measure time between when an event occurred compared to another point in time. In that case I suggest using `performance.now()` which is a high-res monotonic clock.

```
var startTime = performance.now();
$('li').on('click', function(e) {
   var delta = performance.now() - startTime;
   $(this).append('<span class="date">' + delta + ' ms ago, ' + e.type + '</span>');
});
```